# Значение слова «заносит» в контексте

Tags: лексика

Добрый вечер! Что означает «заносит» в этом фрагменте из книги «Воображение и мышление» Г. Г. Гачева?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

«Оно» - это воображение.

Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите цитату из текста. Без нее непонятно, в чем суть вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из значений слова "занести" (см. [здесь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/63074), например):

> 7. безл., кого (что). О состоянии потери самообладания, самоконтроля (разг.). Докладчика занесло, говорит непонятно о чём.

**Воображение заносит** — имеется в виду, что оно отрывается от реалий.

Comment: Интересно, что таким образом после «оно» идут глаголы и в личной, и в безличной форме. Неподумал об этом, искал значение в личной форме.

Получается: «Оно всегда забегает вперед и [оно] заносит».

По значению все-таки в переводе буду «дешифровать» так:

«Оно всегда забегает вперед и теряет самообладание». Это более подходит по контексту чем «отрыв от реалий»; стиль неразговорный - использование слова «заносит» в таком контексте меня дополнительно ввело в недоразумение:)

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, "дешифруйте" так:  «Оно всегда забегает вперед и теряет самоконтроль». В том смысле, что оно делает непоследовательные (неоправданные, нелогичные) выводы, что-то фантазирует, и т.п. "Потерять самообладание" может человек — он тогда может кричать, грубить, хулиганить. Понятие "самоконтроль" чуть шире, в частности включает в себя "связь с реальностью". Слово "заносит" не так уж редко используется в литературной речи.

Answer (score 2):

В этом контексте "Оно" (воображение) *увлекает* своего носителя абстрактными идеями, *отвлекая* его от конкретной темы размышлений - как бы "**занося**" человека мыслями в другую область, о которой он не планировал поразмыслить, уводя его мыслями *по сторонам и в бок* (по тексту). Известное выражение из психологического трактата на эту тему, в вольном переводе с английского: "не человек думу думает, а дума сама себя мыслит посредством человека", мол человек далеко не всегда волен решить: сейчас я буду думать только об этом.

Comment: А по-моему, здесь значение "направить куда-то далеко": по ссылке 2. кого (что). Доставить, направить куда-н. очень далеко или не туда, куда следует. Судьба занесла его на север. Занесло (безл.) его в незнакомый город. Просто в переносном смысле, метафора

Comment: Вопрос не стоял о возможных значениях слова вообще. У автора оно употреблено в контексте роли воображения в процессе познания.

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо за ответы - цитата будет использована в тексте на другом языке, и в переводе я просто вставлю «...» вместо «заносит» (Соломоново решение). :) Полный перевод каждого слова не нужен, главная мысль цитаты будет сохранена.

Но вопрос сам по себе интересен. Автор цитируемого текста Г. Г. Гачев - болгарского происхождения; может быть, это имеет какое-то значение (хотя он родился и жил в СССР). Но более вероятно, что это просто другой уровень языка - собственный, созданный язык: философам так можно, нам - нельзя! :)

Кстати, не уверен, прозвучал ответ на мой вопрос-комментарий: «...После «оно» идут глаголы и в личной, и в безличной форме.

Получается: «Оно всегда забегает вперед и [оно] заносит». Это возможно по-русски, в таком «философически сокращенном» предложении? Т. е. родительный(?) падеж «оно» есть «его»? Если должно быть «Оно всегда забегает вперед и [его] заносит», то это предложение просто не будет соответствовать оригиналу... Но если возможен вариант: «Оно всегда забегает вперед и [оно] заносит», - все хорошо, «респект» супероригинальному автору! :)

Comment: Juozas Rimas, я исправила ошибки в Вашем ответе - обратите внимание на исправления. Верный ответ на вопрос последнего абзаца - оно забегает вперёд и <оно> заносит... к чёрту на рога. "Спасибом" на этом сайте работает оценка за ответ - клик по верхнему треугольничку, ну а суперспасибо - выбор лучшего ответа - клик по нижней галочке.

Comment: Спасибо за исправления (Боже мой, сколько...). «Язик» сам исправлял, не понимаю, почему только в одном месте... По части исправления «...предложения как в оригинале, просто не может быть» на «не будет соответствовать оригиналу»: я хотел спросить/сказать, что такая (первая) интерпретация не то что не будет соответствовать оригиналу, но просто потверждает, что оригинал не правильный, она не возможна «даже в «философическом» языке.

Answer (score 1):

Дорогой Юозас, примите мои глубочайшие соболезнования: книга, на которую Вы ссылаетесь, обманула Вас.

Вам не надо искать значения слова "заносит" хотя бы потому, что переводчик очень плохо владеет русским языком: приходится просто угадывать, что он там имел в виду и куда его занесло.

Даю тот фрагмент, на который Вы ссылаетесь, но читатели его не видят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая строка оборвана, но мы понимаем, что оборвано именно слово "заносит".

(Кстати, употреблённое дважды в тексте, оно несёт разную смысловую нагрузку, имеет разное лексическое значение).

Делаем попытку разобрать все речевые ошибки в этом крошечном фрагменте.

> А в какую грандиозность представлений нас этим образом заносит!

Я не буду останавливаться на том, что кто-либо, занесённый в "грандиозность представлений этим образом", - это не русский язык: нельзя, и всё тут.

Но само слово "заносит" здесь употреблено верно (в том же значении использовала его и я, сказав "куда его занесло"):

[ЗАНЕСТИ (2).](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&all=x)

> Заставить оказаться, очутиться где-л. *Судьба занесла меня в северные
>   края; Его занесло в чужой город; Куда Вас занесла нелегкая?; Кто в
>   этот край тебя занес?*

Вторично употреблённое слово *(Оно <воображение> всегда забегает вперёд и заносит<...>)* имеет значение

[ЗАНЕСТИ (4).](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&all=x)

> Отклонить, резко повернуть в сторону, накренить (при движении).
>   *Прицеп занесло. Сани занесло в сторону.*

Примеры не совсем удачны, однако можно понять, что упомянутое воображение, склонное к аффектации, возносит ("заносит") нас в горние выси - к идеалу (недостижимому по определению).

Вернёмся к другим неточностям крошки-текста - чтобы окончательно дискредитировать перевод и переводчика, чтобы Вы не искали глубинных смыслов в этом псевдорусском языке.

*...Уже знаемым нами* - нет такой формы у глагола "знать" - *знаемым*... Могло бы быть: *познанных нами, знакомых нам.*

*Полномощный посланник (в государстве познания)* - на русский слух это фрагмент юморески - настолько всё пафосно, вычурно и в результате смешно. Но, если брать голые факты, а не возможную реакцию, ио не существует слова "полномощный" (полная мощь, силущка богатырская), а -

**[полномочный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)**!

В современном тексте очень несвоевременным и даже нелепым воспринимается слово "сопутник" (как, впрочем, и "двигатели волевые"):

[СОПУТНИК](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1035782)

> (книжн. поэт. устар.). Спутник. *«Теон… вдруг видит Эсхина, и вмиг
>   узнает сопутника юныя жизни»*. Жуковский.

(Обратите внимание на словарные пометы.)

Ну а завершающее

> А пока суть да дело...

забивает последний гвоздь в гроб переводчика.

См. [Об искажении пословиц и поговорок](http://uknigi.ru/ob_iskajenii_poslovic_i_pogovorok/page/2.html%20%C2%A9%20Uknigi.ru)

**«Суть да дело...»**

> Что означает это выражение? Какая суть и при чем тут дело? А при том,
>   что это выражение употребляется всеми в искаженном виде.
>
> Первоначально
>   существовало выражение «Суд да дело», в котором отразилась волокита
>   старинного судопроизводства: пока происходили «суд да дело», то есть
>   тянулась длительная тяжба, многое могло измениться. Вот в чем был
>   смысл этой старинной поговорки...

Comment: Не по существу замечаний, но: автор — доктор филологических наук [Гачев Георгий Дмитриевич](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2,_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) — вряд ли нуждался в переводчике.

Comment: Вот у него, несмотря на докторскую степень, и получилась смесь французского с нижегородским.  Маленькое лирическое отступление. Одна русская девочка, тонкой душевной организации, попала  (дело давнее) на Украину, надолго. Первые слова, которые она увидела, выйдя в город, были "Пральня" и "Едальня". Она надолго слегла с нервным приступом и затяжной депрессией.

Answer (score 1):

Предварительная замечание. Книга написана весьма специфическим языком, не всегда и понятно без широкого контекста, что хотел автор сказать.

Обнаружил я там два вхождения.

~1. 
В первом случае "**А в какую грандиозность событий оно нас заносит...**"  (Дальше прочитать не удалось)

Здесь, очевидно, имеется в виду несовершенный вид к глаголу "заносить". 
Есть три (из четырех) значений более или менее подходящих по значению.

> ЗАНЕСТИ, -несу, -несёшь; занёс, -несла, -ло; занесённый; -сён, -сена,
>   -сено; св. 1. кого-что. Принести куда-л. мимоходом, по пути. З. приятелю книгу. З. болезнь, заразу, эпидемию. // Разг. Унести не туда,
>   куда нужно; потерять. Куда-то я занесла ножницы. 2. кого-что.
>   Заставить оказаться, очутиться где-л. Судьба занесла меня в северные
>   края. □безл. Его занесло в чужой город. 3. кого-что. Принести, внести
>   куда-л. З. вещи в дом. З. ребёнка в комнату.

Ближе всего здесь значение под номером 2. Но у автора оно использовано в переносном смысле. Его заносит (перемещает) не в прямом значении, а виртуально, мысленно. И не в физическую какую-то реальность, а в условный "мир мысли". Вся фраза обычным языком предаётся ***"[Что-то там] открывает широкие возможности для размышлений, мысленных построений"***

Я не поленился разобрать этот фрагмент, хотя подозоеваю, что вас интересует другой. Автор, видимо использует одно значение в обоих случаях - и это дает некоторый ключ у пониманию.

~2.
**Оно всегда забегает вперед и заносит...**
Здесь, полагаю, "заносит" автора, потерявшего в погоне за красивым словцом чувство грамматики русского языка. Глагол "заносить" в таком употреблении становится двухвалентным: требует указания не только "заносит - ("кто? что?"), но и прямого дополнения - заносит (кого?, что?). Явно, что автор не это хотел сказать.

Судя по всему, автор здесь неграмотно использовал то же значение, что и в первом случае. ***Какое-то чувство (воображение) заносит/переносит автора в какие-то размышления(?)*** Ничего более предположить не могу. Но, повторюсь, здесь у него проявилась стилистическая ошибка, причем довольно грубая.

*О наличии стилистической ошибки говорит, кстати, и то, что уже ответившие до меня поняли ещё каждый по-своему. Я не согласен с большинством трактовок в других ответах по обоим примерам, но не буду комментировать.*